# iPod not connecting to Windows 7 PC

Tags: windows-7, itunes, battery, ipod

I have an old iPod which is not connected to my Windows 7 PC. I have iTunes in my PC but still nothing works.

Actually I have't use it in last one month, yesterday I have try to ON it but battery is low so I connected it with PC but it neither charge nor shown any notification of any device is connected to it.

Then I have tried to charge it with direct power supply but nothing work. Don't know what happen but works fine when I last used it.

Comment: to clarify... the last time the iPod worked, it worked fine.  Now, it won't turn on, and when you connect it to a Windows 7 PC it doesn't indicate it is charging, and iTunes doesn't come up.  Did you try leaving it plugged in so that it could charge enough to display a charge indicator?  It might not matter though... if it is an old iPod, the battery might be shot, or the 1.8" mini HD might be  dead...

Comment: Do you have only one cable? Try a different one

Comment: @BonGart it show charging but when I disconnect it after 2-3 hours it alert no battery and when I connect it to PC Itunes doesn't come up.

Comment: @Darius Yes I have only one cable.

Comment: @BonGart any way to change battery in old iPod as they are out of market.

Comment: Yes.  There are cheap kits like this one http://www.amazon.com/Maximal-Power-Replacement-Battery-iPod/dp/B002BDU6IU/ref=sr_sp-atf_title_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1376139520&sr=8-1&keywords=ipod+battery+kit that come with tools and a battery... of course, it depends on the exact iPod model.